# How do I redirect inbound http API calls to localhost

Tags: iis, network-programming, windows-11

All of this in on Windows 11 without Windows Defender Firewall:

In order to debug an API, I launch an instance of it in Visual Studio which opens a browser to http://localhost:#### where the #### is some port number. That allows me to use Postman on the same computer to make API calls.

What I need to do is use a mobile app to make the same calls, so I replace the server name in my app with the local IP address of my computer. When the mobile device calls the API, it knows enough to ask permission to do things on my local network, but I wind up getting a 400 error in response to the API call.

Basically, in Postman I use http://localhost:12345/SomeEndpoint which works, but when I change localhost to my computer's IP address, it doesn't - even in Postman on the same computer.
(that port values is made up for this example)

I've made attempts at using IIS with Application Request Routing and URL Rewrite, but I'm a novice at best when it comes to those things. Currently, I can use either the ipaddress or localhost to get the default website that is installed with IIS, but when I add the port number, it gets "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."

So, what I'm trying to figure out is how to make the computer redirect incoming IPAddress:port to localhost:port.

Comment: Very likely your IIS site binding was configured to only allow localhost traffic, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Then all external requests end up with 400 (as the host name won't match).

Comment: Use the command line to view the listening list of the HTTP service. Open CMD,
Enter the following command and press Enter: `netsh http show iplisten`.
This will display a list of IP addresses that the HTTP service is currently listening on. If it returns blank, it will listen on all available IP addresses. What did you get?

Comment: Blank. As I mentioned, I can view the web page from another computer or a mobile device using http;/ipaddress but http:/ipaddress:portnumber gets a 400 error.

Comment: The actual troubleshooting must start from networking. Use network debugging tools like Wireshark to inspect the network traffic between your mobile device and your computer. This can help identify any issues with the requests or responses. It is recommended to find a network expert to assist.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find a network expert on here who would say, "This is why the port number is causing problems" especially since Windows firewall is not active.